# Crash with CUDA/OGL interop

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop

I am trying to setup a little CUDA/GL interop example. I have looked around in the internet, so I found some tutorials with some helpful stuff.

All I want is, is to produce a texture in CUDA and draw it with OpenGL.

The source I have now is crashing my Macbook Pro every time I run it, so I thought that if somebody could take an eye on it, that would be really helpful.

```cpp
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #ifdef _WIN32
    #  define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #  define NOMINMAX
    #  include <windows.h>
    #endif

    // OpenGL Graphics includes
    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #if defined (__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
    #include <GLUT/glut.h>
    #else
    #include <GL/freeglut.h>
    #endif

    // includes, cuda
    #include <cuda_runtime.h>
    #include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

    // Utilities and timing functions
    #include <helper_functions.h>    // includes cuda.h and cuda_runtime_api.h
    #include <timer.h>               // timing functions

    // CUDA helper functions
    #include <helper_cuda.h>         // helper functions for CUDA error check
    #include <helper_cuda_gl.h>      // helper functions for CUDA/GL interop

    #include <vector_types.h>
     const unsigned int window_width  = 512;
     const unsigned int window_height = 512;
    GLuint viewGLTexture;
    cudaGraphicsResource_t viewCudaResource;

    void initGLandCUDA() {
         int argc = 0;
         char** argv = NULL;
         glutInit(&argc, argv);
         glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
         glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
         glutCreateWindow("CUDA GL Interop");

         glewInit();

         glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
         glGenTextures(1, &viewGLTexture);
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, viewGLTexture);
         {
             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
             glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
             glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
         }
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

         cudaGLSetGLDevice(gpuGetMaxGflopsDeviceId());
         cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&viewCudaResource, viewGLTexture, GL_TEXTURE_2D,     cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard);
    }    


    __global__ void renderingKernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t image) {
         unsigned int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
         unsigned int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

         uchar4 color = make_uchar4(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, .3f);
         //if I write in 0, 0 and not x,y, the computer is not crashing, but there is no black pixel at 0,0
         surf2Dwrite(color, image, x, y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
    }


    void callCUDAKernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t image) {
         dim3 block(8, 1, 1);
         dim3 grid(8, 1, 1);
         renderingKernel<<< grid, block>>>(image);
    }

     void renderFrame() {
        cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &viewCudaResource);
        {
            cudaArray_t viewCudaArray;
            checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&viewCudaArray, viewCudaResource, 0, 0));
            cudaResourceDesc viewCudaArrayResourceDesc;
            {
                viewCudaArrayResourceDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
                viewCudaArrayResourceDesc.res.array.array = viewCudaArray;
            }
            cudaSurfaceObject_t viewCudaSurfaceObject;
            checkCudaErrors(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&viewCudaSurfaceObject, &viewCudaArrayResourceDesc));

            callCUDAKernel(viewCudaSurfaceObject);

            checkCudaErrors(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(viewCudaSurfaceObject));
        }
        checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &viewCudaResource));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(0));

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, viewGLTexture);
        {
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
                 glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
                 glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(+1.0f, -1.0f);
                 glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(+1.0f, +1.0f);
                 glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, +1.0f);
            }
            glEnd();
         }
         glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
         glFinish();
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
         initGLandCUDA();

        glutDisplayFunc(renderFrame);
        //glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
        //glutMouseFunc(mouse);
        glutMainLoop();
    }
```

It seems like some kind of out-of-range error, but I am currently out of ideas (btw, this is cc 3.0, running to nVidia 650M).

Edit :
By crashing I mean : crashing. Computer freezes. I can't move my mouse and I have to reboot.

Yes, I have looked in all examples, they are not exactly what I want. Changing them to be want I want results in this problem. If there was any other help in the manual or anywhere else that would help me and I have found I would not bother asking for help. You need to link with cuda_runtime and glut libs

Comment: You should describe the error you're getting.  "crashing" is not descriptive enough.  Do you get any error messages?  What happens exactly? The macbook reboots?  You should do proper cuda error checking, *including* on the kernel calls.  You should provide a short *complete* code that demonstrates the issue.  In fact, SO expects "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  If you're not sure what that means, please *read* the sscce.org website.

Comment: There are a variety of CUDA [graphics samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics) which demonstrate CUDA/OpenGL interop, have you looked at those?  Also, Your kernel appears to be expecting a 2D grid, but you are launching a 1D grid.  Is that your intent?  They `y` value in your kernel is always zero.  You might want to run your kernel with `cuda-memcheck`.

Comment: I have edit my question with answers to your questions.
Btw, I have code to reproduce the problem and whatsoever.


* Please take the time needed and note that RTFM answers are not what we need here. * 

I hope SO states that somewhere too.


Upon that said, the problem actually doesn't seems to be in the kernel launching, since yet it being 1D, it still seems to be writing in memory which should be out-of-range.

Comment: The code you provide should be compilable as-is.  It is not.  Yes, I could guess my way through the header files, make some assumptions about `window_height` and `window_width`, dummy out the `checkCudaErrors` macro or write my own, etc. etc.  I choose not to do that, since SO expects you to provide that.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I guess I have mistaken you were not trying to help, but (as many guys do) just say "RTFM and go away".

I think it is okay now (compiling once you have all the libraries needed).

Comment: @user1525378: Moreover, if I were in your place, I would either debug line by line and end up in the line that crashes, or progressively exclude more and more lines to reach the problem point and then if I see one line in particular is causing the crash and I don't understand why I would ask that specific question. This question seems to be very broad.

Comment: I ask this as a result of more problems - debugging/integrating CUDA with Xcode is not really straight forward (aka I have issues with that too).

Didn't want to bother anyone with those. Anyway, Roger Dahl has solved this and has fixed mine errors, thank you Roger again.

Thank you all for the comments too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a working version of your code. The issues in your code were:

- Your kernel was depending on being launched with 512x512 threads, but you were only launching with 64x1 threads.
- Your kernel was writing to unaligned addresses with surf2Dwrite().
- You were setting up double buffering in OpenGL but you were not swapping the buffers. (`glutSwapBuffers()`).
- You were initializing an `uchar4` with floats.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#  define WINDOWS_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#  define NOMINMAX
#  include <windows.h>
#endif

// OpenGL Graphics includes
#include <GL/glew.h>
#if defined (__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#endif

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <vector_types.h>
const unsigned int window_width  = 512;
const unsigned int window_height = 512;

GLuint viewGLTexture;
cudaGraphicsResource_t viewCudaResource;

#define check(ans) { _check((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void _check(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line)
{
  if (code != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr,"CUDA Error: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
    exit(code);
  }
}

void initGLandCUDA() {
  int argc = 0;
  char** argv = NULL;
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(window_width, window_height);
  glutCreateWindow("CUDA GL Interop");

  glewInit();

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glGenTextures(1, &viewGLTexture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, viewGLTexture);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, window_width, window_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  check(cudaGLSetGLDevice(0));

  check(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&viewCudaResource, viewGLTexture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsWriteDiscard));
}    


__global__ void renderingKernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t image) {
  unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  uchar4 color = make_uchar4(x / 2, y / 2, 0, 127);
  surf2Dwrite(color, image, x * sizeof(color), y, cudaBoundaryModeClamp);
}


void callCUDAKernel(cudaSurfaceObject_t image) {
  dim3 block(256, 1, 1);
  dim3 grid(2, 512, 1);
  renderingKernel<<<grid, block>>>(image);
  check(cudaPeekAtLastError());
  check(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

void renderFrame() {
  check(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &viewCudaResource));

  cudaArray_t viewCudaArray;
  check(cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&viewCudaArray, viewCudaResource, 0, 0));

  cudaResourceDesc viewCudaArrayResourceDesc;
  memset(&viewCudaArrayResourceDesc, 0, sizeof(viewCudaArrayResourceDesc));
  viewCudaArrayResourceDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
  viewCudaArrayResourceDesc.res.array.array = viewCudaArray;

  cudaSurfaceObject_t viewCudaSurfaceObject;
  check(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&viewCudaSurfaceObject, &viewCudaArrayResourceDesc));

  callCUDAKernel(viewCudaSurfaceObject);

  check(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(viewCudaSurfaceObject));

  check(cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &viewCudaResource));

  check(cudaStreamSynchronize(0));

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, viewGLTexture);
  {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(+1.0f, -1.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(+1.0f, +1.0f);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, +1.0f);
    }
    glEnd();
  }
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  glFinish();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  initGLandCUDA();

  glutDisplayFunc(renderFrame);
  //glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
  //glutMouseFunc(mouse);
  glutMainLoop();
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: As a result of your help, here is what I got https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rb8kWRwIm1Y